# $resource counterpart in ReactJS and Flux

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I've been working with AngularJS for quite some time and it's really easy to set up a few resources with `$resource` and then talk to an API. But I'm unable to find such a thing in ReactJS/Flux. Is it left for the developer to choose a 3rd party library? If so what is the recommended AJAX library that works nice with ReactJS/Flux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React does not include any support for resources like is available in Angular or even basic Ajax work. You'll need to find a JavaScript library that suits your requirements. [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html) from Facebook may eventually become an interesting option for some scenarios, when they choose to provide the source for it.

Answer (score 2):

Like WiredPrairie says, there is no React support for Ajax requests, in fact in the [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) they use jQuery and notify:

> We included jQuery here because we want to simplify the code of our future ajax calls, but it's NOT mandatory for React to work.

You can search [here](http://microjs.com/#ajax) for a lightweight ajax library if you don't want to include jQuery.
In any case you should wrap the thirdparty ajax library that you choose in a custom object and make all your ajax requests with this object. This will allow you to change the ajax library transparently